# I want to run set of sql script and start the server before running my Cucumber Tests, what is the best possible way to do it

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I want to run few set of sql scripts to insert test data into my data base and have to restart my server and after that i want to start all hmy cucumber tests. how to achieve this using cucumber framework

Answer (score 1):

Rather then trying to test against an existing server, use your build system to start a new server for each cucumber session.

If you're using maven and spring boot you can use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin:start` and `spring-boot-maven-plugin:stop` in the `integration-test` phase.

To insert data in the database you would typically use the same system you use to update your data base in production. If you are using Liquibase you can mark the scripts for test/production to ensure your test data doesn't end up in production.

Comment: My build system starts the server, but i have to create a base data and that base data is cached by there server that's why i need to restart.  i have written scripts independently to start the database as well as to restart my server. As part of cucumber framework what is the best practice to run these scripts. currently i'm using junit Before class method in my runner class to invoke these scripts

Comment: You mean restart the server between tests or between executions of Cucumber? If the latter, why not disable to caching? Restarting/Resetting is generally a bad practice. You want to initialize with a clean state. If you are using a persistent database, why not use an in memory one while testing?

Comment: Thanks for response. Its between execution of cucumber tests, i cannot disable caching even i dont wish to insert data everytime before my test but thats situation we are in currently, i have to do it this way

Comment: If the server has an API accessible by java you could use the Before/After hooks to do so. Though afterwards you should really fix the process that got you into this situation. Testing should be an integrated part of development. Not something done after the fact.

Comment: Not much use I know. But it seems you have a system that has been made rather hard to test.

Comment: Thanks for Ur support, current i'm using Junit before class in my runner to invoke the scripts but was not sure it its best way to do it